# Java code could not load static file from resources

Tags: java, maven

Java code could not load static file from resources folder

```
/etc/services-available/java/testFile.txt (No such file or directory)
```

My code:

```
InputStream testFileContent = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(File.separator+"testFile.txt");

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(testFileContent));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are loaded from within classpath, not filesystem. If you have `/src/main/resources/testFile.txt` it should be loaded with `getResourceAsStream("/testFile.txt")`.

To load a regular file use the `FileInputStream` or the [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) utility class:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/", "etc", "services-available", "java", "testFile.txt");
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for the Java NIO But is there a special reason for separating the directories of the path instead of parse the whole path as one string?

Comment: @Ox1C1B it's more useful on Windows to avoid the dreadful `\\` in the path. I guess it's habit.

Comment: @karol_dowbecki Really? Seems to be logical... I thought I read for a longer time that the JVM internal convert the path system depended so it doesn't really matter if you use "\" or "/"... But okay most of time for platform independent software I used `File.separator` or equivalent options... Learned something again

Comment: @0x1C1B `Paths.get("\\etc\\default\\grub")` is not the same as `Paths.get("/etc/default/grub")` on my Linux. I'm not familiar with this internal conversion, where is it explained?

Comment: @karol_dowbecki Oh I think I will not find this article again I believe it was an answer of a StackOverflow member... But as I already said I still tried to prevent such platform specific features like paths... So I've no idea, I just remember hazy about something like this but no guarantee :)